# set a foreign key in a NodeJS model using sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, sequelize.js, foreign-keys

I'm actually trying to set a foreign key in my model "Batiment" that references the primary key of the model "Zone". I found the sequelize doc. and tried to use it but I got some errors that i couldn't fix. So here i am to ask for help...

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const zone = require("../models/Zone.model.js");

    var Batiment = sequelize.define("batiment", {

            id: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true
            },
            nom: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            code_batiment: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                unique: true
            },
            d_creation: {
                type: Sequelize.DATE,
                defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
            },
            d_modification: {
                type: Sequelize.DATE
            },
        },
    {
            tableName: 'batiment',
            createdAt: false,
            updatedAt: false,


        });
    Batiment.associate = (models) => {
        Batiment.belongsTo(zone, {foreignKey: 'ZoneID', as: 'ZoneID'});
    };
    return Batiment;
};
```

I also found some similar problems on the forum with solutions that i've tried to applicate but with no success.

If someone can explain me what am I doing wrong and what I can do to fix it, I would be very grateful.